# inline CSS to align a social share icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using social share buttons on my site from ShareThis. I'm having some alignment issues with the Facebook Like button.
See screenshot.

[image]

I'd like some direction on the syntax for incline CSS to help align or pad the Facebook line button so it aligns vertically with the others.
I tried many different combinations of doing this including adding `style="padding-bottom:25px"`

This is the HTML code provided by ShareThis:

```
<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
<span class='st_googleplus_large' displayText='Google +'></span>
<span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
<span class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
<span class='st_fblike_large' displayText='Facebook Like'></span>
<span class='st_plusone_large' displayText='Google +1'></span>
```

Added these lines to bottom of file

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=false;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "ur-22cc647b-2be-2114-fe32-8c2f8b9ab95e", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

Comment: Java? Looks like HTML to me. Please add a jsFiddle.

Comment: @StefanSurkamp JavaScript

Comment: The first fragment of code is html markup, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

As the max-height of all your spans are 32px at the most you should add this to your stylesheet

```
span {display:inline-block; height:32px; line-height:32px;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dPxVm/2/)

Please note it would probably be best to give all your spans a class and then style that rather than styling the span tag as above

Answer (score 0):

Put code below on fb span:

```
style="display: inline-block; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; vertical-align: top;"
```

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle for below code. you just needd to replace text with your images.

```
<div style="float:left;">  

<span style="display:inline;"></span>                               
<span style="display:inline; "></span>                                    

</div>
```

See js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LurGq/7/)